# Minimum installations for using CPA in Mbile App Install ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

When I try to create mobile app install using CPA I get the following error

> (Exception - #1487579) Your account does not have enough install history to start using cost per action (CPA) bidding for mobile app install ads. Please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/ to learn more.

This is what I found in Facebook's documentation:

> You will not be able to buy CPA for mobile app installs unless you have already reported back some installs and your account id-app id-mobile store trio has been deemed non-fraudulent. In the meantime, your ad creation call will fail.

What is the specific amount of installations required in order to allow the usage of CPA ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific amount that has been published, however the recommendation would be to use oCPM with an action value equal to the CPA you are willing to pay until this threshold has been met.

oCPM will aim to optimize for a maximum action value so you will achieve essentially the same results.

Comment: i have same problem. i didn't find any solution. And i did't understand your answer.

Comment: Your account does not have enough install history to start using billing event for mobile app install ads. Please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/ to learn more. i got this error while set "app install on when you are charged".

Comment: the solution is to run some ads using billing event of impressions, then after FB sees a consistent install ratio, the billing event of app installs will be available

Comment: Any new updates , I've made about 5K paid installs through facebook. Still can't use CPA bid.

Comment: @Fadi did you fix it ?